# Why can I see some SQL Server DB user's effective permissions and others not, when i am a sysadmin

Tags: sql-server, privileges

I am a sysadmin on an SQL Server instance. I have created and added an AD group to manage security to the server logins and have also mapped it to a database with db_datareader and db_datawriter roles...

If I navigate to the database and look at the permissions for the added group, I can see the explicit but NOT the effective permissions, I get the message "cannot execute as the server principal because the principal does not exist this type of principal cannot be impersonated, or you do not have permission"

If I do the same for the next user in the list I can see both explicit and effective permissions, etc etc, until I hit another user and get the same message.

I have tried to add a single AD user to DB logins and I can see both explicit and effective. 
I have tried to add a different AD group on a different database and I get the error

Answer (score 2):

This is because to check the effective permissions `SSMS` tries to execute the code like this:

```
execute as login = '...';
select *
from sys.fn_my_permissions(null, 'server');
```

here '...' is the login for whom's permissions you are looking for.

But the login that is a `Windows Group` **cannot be impersonated**,

so the first statement `execute as login = 'MyADGroup';` gives you an error
"cannot execute as the server principal because the principal does not exist **this type of principal cannot be impersonated**, or you do not have permission".

To check the effective permissions of the group you can execute this code by yourself with some **member** of this Group in `execute as login`

And here is BOL article [EXECUTE AS (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/execute-as-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) that says:

> { EXEC | EXECUTE } AS    [;]
>   ::=   { LOGIN | USER } = 'name'
>       [ WITH { NO REVERT | COOKIE INTO @varbinary_variable } ]    | CALLER
>   ...
>
> **name** must be a singleton account, and **cannot be a group**,
>   role, certificate, key, or built-in account, such as NT
>   AUTHORITY\LocalService, NT AUTHORITY\NetworkService, or NT
>   AUTHORITY\LocalSystem.

Comment: Does this also show permissions granted by roles, such as built-in roles? I find that SSMS misses those in its Effective permissions menu.

Comment: It does show all the effective permissions, those granted by roles included, but also SSMS shows them